# Default MVC5 Application will not run out of debug mode in browser VS Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have just started to develop an application in Visual Studio 2013 using MVC5. I am using the default MVC application, I have made no changes. I find that running the application works fine while in debug mode however if I Stop Debugging Shift F5 and change from on page to another or refresh my application in the browser I find that the connection to the localhost server is disconnected. I get a message Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost: I have tested another application developed in Visual Studio 2012 and now running on VS2013 and it runs as expected out of debug mode. Has anybody else come across this problem. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I see the same behavior in VS2013 as well as VS2013. So I think when you do "F5" debugging and when you stop the debugging, it suppose to lose the connection.

Comment: Sorry I mean I see the same behaviour in VS2013 as well as VS2012 :)

Comment: As I have stated in my question I have developed many other applications in Visual Studio Express and have never come across this behaviour in the past. I have migrated an application from VS2012 to VS2013 and it does not lose the connection to the server when you stop debugging. I can start the application without debugging and it does not lose the connection to the server, it is only when I start the application in debug mode and stop debugging that I lose the connection to the server and I have noticed this same behaviour in the SPA templates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have Edit and Continue enabled?  (This can be found under your projects Properties -> Web, at the bottom.

When you have Edit and Continue enabled, the VS debugger attaches invasively to the web server process (IIS Express).  When you stop the debugger, this kills the IIS Express process as well.  If E&C is turned off, the debugger does not use an invasive attach, which lets the debugger stop without killing the attached process.

Comment: Ok! Jimmy give yourself a high five, I have never used this before it must be enabled by default on new projects, thanks this was the problem.

Comment: Why MS does these annoying things, i donno.