# How can I test MVC changes by refreshing the browser?

Tags: c#, testing, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I know there's a way to, in Visual Studio, test a change by getting the page running in the browser, and then by just refreshing the browser page rather than by rerunning the application.  But although it was working before, it isn't working now, and I'm fairly new to MVC, so I don't remember what I was doing to make it work.  Instead, I'm having to actually re-run the application each time.

Specifically, I 1) run from VS, 2) copy the URL from the webpage I just launched, 3) stop debugging from VS (and the browser closes), 4) paste that URL into a new browser window and hit enter, 5) get "This webpage is not available" from Chrome and "This page can't be displayed" from IE.

I'm using VS Express 2013, and was also using that when it was working.  I've tried with both IE and Chrome, and I've rebooted my computer and cleared my cache.  What did I do wrong / how do I fix it?  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache?

Comment: Thanks, I did that just now but it didn't help.

Comment: If you stop debugging it shuts your local server down and you will get what you are seeing... "webpage not available". You can keep your localhost running and change your razor/html and refresh the page. A code change will require a rebuild (Although I think VS14 will allow you to do hot edits in MVC)

Comment: This is part of it, thanks! The rest is in my answer, below.  It wouldn't let me make code changes at all while still running because "Enable Edit and Continue" was set, which makes a tight attachment between IIS and the debugger.  Unchecking that will allow the web site to continue running even when the debugger is stopped, so I can edit my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched SO for an answer before, but couldn't find one until after I'd posted mine (doh!).  This question has the answer I wanted.  [Default MVC5 Application will not run out of debug mode in browser VS Express 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157417/default-mvc5-application-will-not-run-out-of-debug-mode-in-browser-vs-express-20)

The issue was that I couldn't edit code (I could edit cshtml) when the debugger was still running.  You can disconnect the running debugger and still keep the IIS session active if you uncheck Project Properties / Web / Enable Edit and Continue.

Answer (score 0):

Install IIS locally on the machine you run visual studio on.  Create a new site in IIS and point it's path to the path of your MVC project.  Change the application pool for it to use .net 4 and set the identity on the application pool to your user account.

Then give it a binding of something like localdev and a host header in your hosts file, then just build the site and go to http colon localdev in the browser.

It will reset the app pool automatically when the build changes.

The way I build sites is I virtualize.  I use Oracle VirtualBox and install windows server 2008 r2 (or windows 7 x64) to a virtual machine in virtual box.  Then I install Sql Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2013.  Then I install Toirtoise SVN and Visual SVN extensions and get the source code from our sub version server and set up websites in IIS similar to how we set them up in production.  Then when I want to debug code I just attach the debugger to ws3p.exe.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this if necessary. But it was working before, and I know that just generally to test I can use the IIS built into VS.  I don't intend to deploy and host from my machine.